# Add folder to unmanagedResourceDirectories only for "sbt run"

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am new to Scala and sbt (0.13.13) - I started using Play Framework (2.5.10) a few weeks ago.

My question:
I added

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory( _ / "devstuff" ).value
```

to the `build.sbt`. This is because I want all the files (these are not source files) in `devstuff` on the classpath (only) during developing my app (when running `sbt run`). Also, when editing a file in `devstuff` the application gets restarted/re-compiled. That's fine and that's what I want for development.

However when running `sbt dist`, `sbt stage`, `universal:packageZipTarball`, etc. - when I create the final distribution package - I do not want that this folder gets included. The folder only contains stuff needed during developing, but I don't want it packaged in my final package.

How can I achieve that the `myfolder` is in `unmanagedResourceDirectories` for `sbt run` (and also `sbt test`) but not for creating the distribution packages?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html) you should be able to use the `Runtime` scope to achieve this:

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Runtime += baseDirectory( _ / "devstuff" ).value
```